# Android : How to call activity inside running activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am thinking to split the activity into two parts :

1. List view : show the files.
2. Second part will an activity contain the selected file.

its possible to do that, like frames in HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to be doing is using activity fragments. The guide topic [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) describes how to do pretty much exactly what you're talking about. To support pre-3.0 Android systems, you'll need to use the [compatibility package](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html).